# Error Deploying application in WebLogic Server: 12.2.1.3.0 Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: WebLogic_12

Tags: java, deployment, dependencies, web-deployment, weblogic12c

I been deploying an a web aplication in weblogic 12, but the deploy throw this error:

**java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: WebLogic_12**

Stacktrace:

Caused by: **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: WebLogic_12**
            at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:1029)
            at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:990)
            at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:104)
            at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.doFindClass(GenericClassLoader.java:611)
            at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:543)
            at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:496)
            at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:89)
            at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:53)
            at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
            at **org.eclipse.persistence.**internal.security.PrivilegedAccessHelper.getClassForName(PrivilegedAccessHelper.java:124)
            at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.findClass(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1232)
            at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.findClassForProperty(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1238)
            at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.updateServerPlatform(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:936)
            at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1647)
            at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:322)
            at weblogic.persistence.BasePersistenceUnitInfo.initializeEntityManagerFactory(BasePersistenceUnitInfo.java:614)
            at weblogic.persistence.BasePersistenceUnitInfo.init(BasePersistenceUnitInfo.java:202)
            at weblogic.persistence.BaseJPAIntegrationProvider.createPersistenceUnitInfo(BaseJPAIntegrationProvider.java:54)
            at weblogic.persistence.AbstractPersistenceUnitRegistry.storeDescriptors(AbstractPersistenceUnitRegistry.java:422)
            at weblogic.persistence.AbstractPersistenceUnitRegistry.loadPersistenceDescriptors(AbstractPersistenceUnitRegistry.java:128)
            at weblogic.persistence.ModulePersistenceUnitRegistry.(ModulePersistenceUnitRegistry.java:56)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppInternalModuleExtension$PersistenceExtension.setupPersistenceUnitRegistry(WebAppInternalModuleExtension.java:197)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppInternalModuleExtension$PersistenceExtension.access$300(WebAppInternalModuleExtension.java:118)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppInternalModuleExtension.prePrepare(WebAppInternalModuleExtension.java:56)
            at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$PrepareStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:293)
            at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$PrepareStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:285)
            at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
            at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.prepare(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:109)

The jars in my WEB-INF/lib are:

```
all-themes-1.0.10.jar
aristo-1.0.1.jar
c3p0-0.9.1.1.jar
commons-codec-1.3.jar
commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
commons-collections4-4.1.jar
commons-digester-1.7.jar
commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar
commons-io-1.4.jar
commons-javaflow-20060411.jar
commons-logging-1.1.jar
commons-net-2.0.jar
cupertino-1.0.10.jar
curvesapi-1.04.jar
delta-1.0.10.jar
jasperreports-4.1.3.jar
jasypt-1.7.jar
jcommon-1.0.15.jar
jdt-compiler-3.1.1.jar
jfreechart-1.0.12.jar
jsf-api-2.0.3.jar
jsf-impl-2.0.3.jar
jstl-1.0.2.jar
midnight-1.0.10.jar
ojdbc6.jar
overcast-1.0.10.jar
poi-excelant-3.15.jar
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.15.jar
poi-scratchpad-3.15.jar
primefaces-3.5.jar
quartz-jobs-2.2.1.jar
sam-1.0.10.jar
slf4j-api-1.6.6.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.6.6.jar
smoothness-1.0.10.jar
tomahawk20-1.1.14.jar
xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar
```

and my dependencies are:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>3.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.15</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.15</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>au.com.bytecode</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
        <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

and I don´t know whats happend in deploy , all the config files look fine

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I delete weblogic.xml from war archive. It's work for me on WLS 12.2.1.3.